# Why is my Drill up not working with Async DrillDown?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, vuejs3

I have a Highchart with 8-10 series printed in a line chart for 24 different x values. I have applied Async drilldown which prints 24-30 series for same 24 different x values. Till now The code is working as expected. But when I drill up for the same drilldown. My browser is getting hanged till this drill up is not completed and it is taking around 1 min to complete this drill up operation.

Basically, the drill up operation is removing the series for this.drilldownLevels(a variable from Highcharts) one by one and taking around 1 min to complete this.

For Example, if I have 8 series initially, when I drilldown let's say I have 24 series printed using  this.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown then while getting drilled up it has to remove 16(24 - 8) series from this.drilldownLevels. But this operation of drill up is getting my system hanged till the time it completed.

I have tried this.drillUpAll() but its not working as expected.

Comment: Hi @Keshav Agarwal, The `addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown` method is not officially documented, so it may not work properly in every case. However, I've tried to reproduce the issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hgLybcu5/ but everything seems to work as expected.